# Redesign Contacts UI Swift

Tags: swift, contacts, modalviewcontroller

Is there a way I can change the background color in contacts UI? I'm trying to implement various themes, and so I will need to alter the background color.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet